# Why is the image of a smooth embedding $f: N \to M$ an embedded submanifold?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading *An Introduction to Manifolds* (Tu) and got confused on p.123 Theorem 11.13. Let me briefly explain what was done before that.

The author defines an embedding between two manifolds $f: N\rightarrow M$ as an injective immersion (differential is injective everywhere) with the additional property that $f(N)$ as a subspace of $M$ is homeomorphic via $f$ to $N$. Then a canonical form theorem is proven, namely, that for any point $p \in N$, there are charts $(U,\phi = x^1, \ldots, x^n) \ni p$ and $(V,\psi = y^1, \ldots, y^m) \ni f(p)$, such that the transition map takes the following form:

$$\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1} : (r^1,\ldots,r^n) \mapsto (r^1,\ldots,r^n,0,\ldots,0).$$

(I guess it is implicitly assumed that $f(U) \subset V$).

Now in the process of proving that $f(N) \subset M$ is an [embedded submanifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold#Embedded_submanifolds), he states that $f(U) \subset V$ is defined by the vanishing of the coordinates $y^{n+1},\ldots,y^m$. I can prove that
$$
f(U) \subset \{q \in V: y^{n+1}(q) = \cdots = y^m(q)\}
$$
but not the reverse inclusion. Can anyone explain why this should be true?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reverse inclusion doesn't necessarily follow from the canonical form theorem you've stated, since $V$ can just happen to be too large (or, if you like, $U$ can be too small): given $U$ and $V$ as you have one can always replace $U$ by a much smaller neighborhood $U'$ of $0$, and still guarantee that $U'$ and $V$ have charts satisfying your theorem -- and also be sure that the inclusion $\supset$ can't hold.

The solution, of course, is just to prove a slightly better canonical form theorem, by reducing the possible size of $V$:

**Theorem.** For any $p \in N$, there exist charts $(U, \phi = x^1, \dots, x^n)$ and $(V, \psi = y^1, \dots, y^m)$ satisfying 
$$
    \psi f \phi^{-1} : (r^1, \dots, r^n) \mapsto (r^1, \dots, r^n, 0, \dots, 0)
$$
and such that 
$$
  f(U) = \lbrace q \in V : y^{n+1}(q) = \cdots = y^m(q) = 0 \rbrace.
$$

**Proof.** The proof is simple once you have your canonical form theorem; if $(U, \phi)$ and $(V', \psi)$ are the charts guaranteed by your theorem, then you can take
$$
   V = \psi^{-1} \Big( \psi(V') \cap (\phi(U) \times \mathbb{R}^{m-n}) \Big).
$$
Then $(U, \phi)$ and $(V, \psi|_V)$ satisfy the conditions of this new theorem.

Comment: Thank you so much! this does it (had to change U to \phi(U) in the last equation) but that was an obvious fix.

Comment: Your theorem can be generalized to arbitrary smooth maps of constant rank. The rank theorem says that if $F:M\to N$ is a smooth map of constant rank $r$ between manifolds, then for each $p\in M$ there are charts $(U,\varphi)$ for $M$ centered at $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ for $N$ centered at $F(p)$ such that $F(U)\subset V$ and in which $F$ has the coordinate representation of the form
$$
\hat{F}(x^1,\dots,x^r,x^{r+1},\dots,x^m)=(x^1,\dots,x^r,0,\dots,0).
$$
The result of this theorem can be strengthen to say that

Comment: $(U,\varphi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ can be chosen to additionally fulfill $\psi(F(U))=\psi(V)\cap(\mathbb{R}^r\times\{0\}^{n-r})$. The proof is given in John M. Lee _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_, and even though Lee states the rank theorem without this strengthening, after close inspection one can see that the charts that Lee constructs in his proof do satisfy the strengthening. (This is due to the way in which Lee defines the coordinate neighborhood $V_0$.)