# Is this a parametrization of a surface of the form $S=g^{-1}(a)$ where $a$ is a regular value of $g$?

Tags: differential-geometry

If $a$ is a regular value of a function $g:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we define the regular surface $S = g^{-1}(a)$. If U is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $x:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is a differentiable, homeomorphic map such that for each $q\in U$, the differential $dx_q:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ is one-to-one (that is, $x$ satisfies the conditions for a parametrization of $S$), is $x$ automatically a parametrization of $S$?

I think the answer is no, but how the question is asked is a little bit ambiguous for me. We need that for each $p\in S$, then the range of the map $x$ needs to be $V\cap S$ where $V$ is a neighborhood of $p$. Otherwise, we could have that $x$ does not intersect the surface $S$. Am I overcomplicating things?

Comment: Your parametrization takes values in $S$? Take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934112/relation-between-two-different-definitions-of-regular-surface/2935902#2935902, it may be helpful.

Comment: @Laz It does not say that. For that argument, I think the answer of my question is no. But I can't think of a counterexample.

Comment: I'm confused as to what's your definition of parametrization. Is it the one given in do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry (English edition), page 1? I think your parametrization needs to take values in the submanifold $S$, because the idea is that $S$ is locally Euclidean. I think this is semantics, don't get confused and use do Carmo's definition, that is the standard one. Just observe that as the preimage of a regular value, $S$ is a regular submanifold in the sense of the question I posted in my last comment (adapted charts with $0$'s at the end), there I proved both definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @Laz No, I have not seen submanifolds or things like that. The definition I am using is from Do Carmo's differential geometry of curves and surfaces, page 52.

Comment: Yes, it's the same definition in both books. Observe that any parametrization is required to take an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomorphically onto an open subset of $S$, which has the subspace topology, then it has to be $V\cap S$ for $V$ some open in $\mathbb{R}^3$. That's the only thing you have to add so that it is a parametrization of $S$. The rest of your hypothesis are correct.